# google search console discovered urls is too few for sitemap index

Tags: google-search-console

My sitemap index file does not show any errors on google search console, but it only shows 397 discovered urls whereas it should have been over a million.
[image: Wrong number]

Basically my sitemap index file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap><loc>https://www.somesite.com/sitemap1</loc><lastmod>2020-09-14T04:38:25Z</lastmod></sitemap>
  <sitemap><loc>https://www.somesite.com/sitemap2</loc></sitemap>
  <sitemap><loc>https://www.somesite.com/sitemap3</loc></sitemap>
  <sitemap><loc>https://www.somesite.com/sitemap4</loc></sitemap>
  <sitemap><loc>https://www.somesite.com/sitemap5</loc></sitemap>
  ... (614 sitemap entries in total)
</sitemapindex>
```

What can be wrong? Do I have too many `<sitemap>` entries?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: moving to here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132393/google-search-console-discovered-urls-is-too-few-for-sitemap-index

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is moved to here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132393/google-search-console-discovered-urls-is-too-few-for-sitemap-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to combination of having too many sitemap files and some giving timeout errors. Search console is not good at reporting those errors with a lot of sitemaps. The issue is fixed after reducing sitemap count to 200 and making them load under 30 seconds.